# System Backup Over FTP Server

Tags: linux, backup, ftp

I am having a device running 3.0.9 GNU/Linux version which I am accessing over the ftp protocol. I want to create a system backup of that device provided it has only the basic utilities installed and device cannot connect to the internet as well to download any package. Can anyone help?

Comment: With FTP you might not get all metadata like extended attributes not to mention that it would be probably slower, is `ssh` really no option?

Comment: Well, I can try accessing it over SSH connection as well. What would be the procedure in that case?

Comment: If there is also `scp` then `scp -rp user@remote:/remote_path/ /local_path/`

Answer (score 1):

It will be at least hard to do a proper backup over FTP.

Try connect with SSH, and then you can run

```
tar -zcvf backup.tar.gz /
```

Then you can download your archive file from the server using FTP if you want.

**Notice:** make sure that you have enough space on the disk for the entire backup before, or you can find out your system drive full!